# Windows Bluetooth connect

Tags: windows, winapi, mobile

How can we connect bluetooth device in range with Microsoft shared Bluetooth Library? Is it possible?

Can we do that..after that how can we automate the file transfer...?

plz help if anyone does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site tells you all you need to get started:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932%28VS.85%29.aspx